# How can I restrict a user to only add / remove his name from a user group

Tags: user

I have created a user group in sharepoint 2013.
In this group I need to set up an permission level, that the user viewing this group can only add or remove himslef.
He should not be allowed to add or remove other members.

Answer (score 0):

Only Group Owner has permission to Add/Remove members from Group.

To handle your requirement, you need to create custom solution

1. Create a web part
2. You can query the group and list all members
3. You can have a remove button - Clicking button will run `elevated` code to remove current user from group
4. You can have an add button - Clicking button will run `elevated` code to add current user to group